# Azure Web Apps Monitoring Metrics and App Service Plan

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans, azure-monitoring

I am looking into web Apps Monitoring in Microsoft Azure and I can see a variety of options in the portal. I have some questions in those which I will put forward one by one. The question length may be a bit long so apologies in advance :-)

1. Process Explorer

Here we can find process details per instance which are running for my Web App.In case of scale out we will also see multiple instances.  I want to know why we are seeing 2 processes per instance and what is the significance of each process.
[image]

2.Metrics Per Instance (Apps)

While looking at this report, I can see 2 different tabs (see image), I am unable to map it to the instances I am having in my web apps.

2.A) Is it true that If I have multiple deployment slots/ scaled out instances I will see that many tabs in the report?

2.B) Is there a way by which I can map these to my Web App instances in the Process Explorer
[image]

3.Metrics Per Instance App Service Plan
Here Again we have to different indicators same as in Apps. Can some please help me how to decipher these.
[image]

Can you guys please help me out with the reports as it seems to be quite confusing and I am unable to map it with my Instances, Deployment Slots in relation to the app service Plan.

Once again apologies for a long question. 
Thanks in Advance,
Mayank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like no one answered this in a long time. Let me see if I can explain this better.

This blade that you are talking about is accessible under "**Diagnose and solve problems**" options of an App Service Web App. Lot of changes has been made in the last few months to this feature. Read more about it here: [Azure App Service - Diagnostics and Solve](https://azure.github.io/AppService/diagnostics/)

**1. Why we are seeing 2 processes per instance and what is the significance of each process.**

> In Azure App Service. For every web app there is another web app provisioned. This site is known as **KUDU**. So one w3wp.exe corresponds to the process hosting your code and the second w3wp.exe corresponds to the process hosting the KUDU. This process will have a **SCM** tag appended against it. You can read more about it here: [Project Kudu - Github](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki)

**2.Is it true that If I have multiple deployment slots/ scaled out instances I will see that many tabs in the report? Is there a way by which I can map these to my Web App instances in the Process Explorer**

> To answer the first part, YES, the tabs corresponds to the number of instances the app service plan is scaled out to. So if your web app is scaled out to 7 instances, then you will see 7 tabs in the report.

> There is no straight approach to correlate the instance names to process explorer. There is an alternate way. I have a blog post using which you can connect to the KUDU site of a web app on a specific instance. See this: [Connect to Kudu site of a specific instance](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2016/11/21/azure-app-service-how-to-connect-to-the-kudu-site-of-a-specific-instance/)

**3. Metrics Per Instance App Service Plan Here Again we have to different indicators same as in Apps. Can some please help me how to decipher these.**

> as the name says, **Metrics per instance (App Service Plan)** displays data for the entire VM, while **Metrics per Instance (Apps)** displays data for a specific web app or process (w3wp.exe). In Azure App Service, you can provision several web apps inside a VM. So, this view provides a holistic view of the overall usage of the VM. This will help you in determining whether you need to scale out or scale up.

I hope this answers this question.

Comment: thanks.. This really helped... Thanks for being generous to answer a question which is sitting idle for a long time..

Comment: This [App Lens - Azure App Service](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/06/02/applens/) is broken...

Comment: fixed the broken link.